# Rails -- reroute only one of the resource routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, restful-architecture

I have a resource called Entries, which has all the normal default RESTful routes that go along with a resource.  I want to leave all the routes as they are EXCEPT I want the `show` action to be rerouted to my Articles controller (`Articles#show`).  Here is my current (but not working) code in my routes file:

```
resources :entries do
    member do
      get 'entry' => 'articles#show'
    end
  end
```

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?  I want to leave all the other routes from the Entries resource exactly as they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add a match before the resource articles.
If I understand, you want the route /entries/1/entry to go to the articles show?
Else just change the match line with what you want.

```
match "entries/:id/entry" => "articles#show"

resources :articles
resources :entries
```

Comment: I had wanted `match entries/:id` to go to the articles show, but your solution worked.